# How to get didselectrowat from a custom cell with textboxes?

Tags: swift, uitableview, textbox

I have a dynamic tableview with 3(cell1,cell2,cell3) custom cells, which gets reused anywhere from 0 times up to 9 times. (Maximum cells in the tableview will be 27 cells).

Each of those 3 custom cells have 3 text boxes each, and in addition the second cell has 2 buttons to select gender and 3rd custom cell has a drop down menu, which has values of whatever typed in the first textbox of cell1 cells.

Now the issue is that, textbox takes the touch input from user (as it should) and didselectrowat never gets called and therefore i am not getting indexPath.
But i need the indexPath, so that i can insert user details from each of those cells into an array.

```
(anArray.insert("", at: indexPath)
```

Since i am not getting indexPath, everything fails. How can i get the indexPath and get the touch on to the textbox?

I am thinking of something like a function that takes the touch ,gets the indexPath and then passes the control to textbox.

Things i have tried.

I disabled the textboxes before user touches the cell (and makes textboxes disabled once user deselects the cell, so cell takes the touch. Once didselectrowat gets called, make the textbox active again and make

```
textbox.becomeFirstResponder()
```

But somehow , the textbox never becomes the first responder even though breakpoint shows the control going through it and the textbox becomes active. But no keyboard popsup, if i touch the cell again, same process happens.

What seems to be the issue here? I saw another post  on the same topic, i tried it but unfortunately that doesnt work and it was for a static tableview.

Also is there a good way to do this? Other than making the user click on the cell twice / clicking outside the textbox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your custom cell as `delegate` for `UITextField` and use a callback  for editing begins/ends as below,

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    public var editCallback: (() -> Void)?

    /// Set 'textField.delegate = self' on initialization.

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
         self.editCallback?()
    }
}
```

And use the callback in `cellForRowAt` as,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = MyCustomCell()
    cell.editCallback = { [weak self] in
        print(indexPath)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)



        //your code here

    }
```

Comment: What?!.....I select indexPath and then deselect it instantly? Please read the question